# Suppose X is an infinite collection, is it locally connected with the finite complement?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

I already proved that X is connected. I first thought connected implied locally connected until i saw the topologist sine curve.

following the definition that we need to check that for every $x\in X$ and $U$ such that $x\in U$, there is a connnected $V \subset U$.

I thought if $U$ is not connected, then I could split up $U=K \cup L$ and let's say $x\in K$, then I take $V=K$. If $K$ is not connected I would split it up again till I get only one connected neighborhood of $x$.

My question is, if $U$ is connected, can I just take $V=U$?

Kees

Comment: can one answer his own question because is already solved it by now

Answer (score 0):

Since X is infinite we know that for every two non empty open sets $U_1$,$U_2$ $;$ $U_1\cap U_2$$\neq$$\emptyset$

For every (non empty) open set V$\subset$$X$ ,$V$ is connected:

$Proof$:

Suppose we can find a partition.The open sets in $V$ are also open in $X$.

So given $V_1$,$V_2$ such that $V_1$$\cup$$V_2$=$V$ $\implies$ $V_1$$\cap$$ V_2$$\neq$$\emptyset$.

Then V is connected.

We can conclude by choosing $V$=$U$

Comment: I have proven already that no partition is possible for X and so X is connected. But my question is if it's also locally connected. Because not all connected spaces are locally connected.

Comment: I edited the answer, is it clear now?